# c# webrequest post form-data

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a Postman that do success post call to website using form-data:

[image]

How can I post using form-data same as postman in c#?

I was doing but is not working.

```
string formParams = string.Format("Email={0}&Password={1}&ufprt={2}", "123@gmail.com", "test", key);
                string cookieHeader;


                getRequest = WebRequest.Create(baseaUrl);
                getRequest.ContentType = "application/form-data";
                getRequest.Method = "POST";

                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
                getRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                using (Stream sr = getRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    sr.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                }

                getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you get?  Exception?  Error response (in which case which HTTP Status and body)?  Do you have to use `WebRequest`; `HttpClient` is so much easier to use...

Comment: Dont get exception but HTML returned is not the one after login.

Comment: Is there perhaps a 302 Redirect happening that `WebRequest` is not following?  Postman can follow redirects automatically.  If you think that might be the case, turn off following redirects in Postman (in the settings) and see whether it now shows the same as your coded response.

Comment: There's always a `302` after a successful LogIn (because you're redirected to the Landing page). If the LogIn is invalid, you get back the Login Form and `StatusCode` is 200. Add `getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;` after `.Create`. You may also want to add a working `CookieContainer` to the `WebRequest`. That `string cookieHeader;` is sitting there without any visible role (and it's a `string`). Also to note that `application/form-data` should be used for binary data. `ASCII` encoding may work or may not. I, usually, use `UTF8.GetBytes()`. With Text, of course.